# how to get data from json object to a dictionary in python

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

i send data from javascript to views,py using the following javascript code

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("js2 working");
  var jsonData={},a=0,key;
  $("#submit-button").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.field').each(function () {
    a+=1;
    key=String(a);
    jsonData[key] = this.value;
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
  $.get('details',{"data":JSON.stringify(jsonData)}).done(function(){

 console.log("posted successfully");
});
});
});
```

i get a json string:

```
{"1":"text","2":"text2",3:"text3"}
```

int the views.py using request.get
i need to extract each value in views.py

here is my code in views.py:

```
def details(request):
  latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('id')
  count=0
  for question in latest_question_list:
    count+=1
    answer=request.GET['data']
    jsonData=json.loads(answer)
    answer=jsonData(str(count))
    entry = Answer(question = question,answer=answer)
    entry.save()
  return HttpResponse("feedback:contactus")
```

i am getting the json in views.py as shown above the problem is while trying to extract value. please help me find a solution

Comment: what is the error exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonData` is converted to a dictionary so that you can do the following:

```
>>> print len(jsonData)
3
>>> print text = jsonData['1']
'text'
>>> print jsonData['2']
'text2'
>>> print jsonData['3']
'text3'
```

---

As for your question:

```
answer = request.GET['data']
jsonData = json.loads(answer)

for count, question in enumerate(latest_question_list):
    answer = jsonData[str(count + 1)]
    entry = Answer(question=question, answer=answer)
    entry.save()

return HttpResponse("feedback:contactus")
```

Comment: Thanks mate i have been struggling to find this small mistake for a long time